# Python:Selecting a range of lines from one file and copying it to another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I have a file and i want to select certain lines in the file and copy it to another file.

In the first file the line where i want to copy has the word "XYZ" and from here i want to select the next 200 lines(including the match line) and copy it to another file.

The below is my code

```
match_1 = 'This is match word'
with open('myfile.txt') as f1:
     for num, line in enumerate(f1, 1):
        if log_1 in line:
            print line
```

The above code leads me to the start of the line and i need to select 200 lines form the matched line and then copy,move it to another text file.

I tried couple of options like while statements,but i am not able to build the logic fully.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.islice` on the file object once the match is found:

```
from itertools import islice

# some code before matching line is found
chunk = line + ''.join(islice(f1, 200))
```

This will consume the iterator `f1` to the next 200 lines, and so the `num` count in your loop may not be coherent if this is placed in your loop.

If you do not need the other lines in the file after finding the match, you can use:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('myfile.txt') as f1, open('myotherfile.txt') as f_out:
     for num, line in enumerate(f1, 1):
        if log_1 in line:
            break
     chunk = line + ''.join(islice(f1, 200))
     f_out.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Thanks Moses for your quick response.This exactly solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
>>> with open("pokemonhunt", "r") as f:
...   Lines = []
...   numlines = 5
...   count = -1
...   for line in f:
...     if "pokemon" in line:           % gotta catch 'em all!!!
...       count = 0
...     if -1 < count < numlines:
...       Lines.append(line)
...       count += count
...     if count == numlines:
...       with open("pokebox","w") as tmp: tmp.write("".join(Lines))
```

Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: (obviously, if you expect more than one matches, change the outfile name each time, or append to the same file, etc)

Comment: Thanks Tasos for your quick response....actually i wanted to open a file and search for a word in the file.Once i get the match,i need to copy the next 200 lines and put in a new file for further analysis.I will try to add more clarity to my question next time...

Comment: yes, this is what this does. ( if your word is "pokemon" and you want 5 lines :p )

Comment: ok Tasos..i will give a try for this logic as well..thanks again